# Most common way of writing a HTML table with vertical headers?

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup

What's your preferred way of writing HTML tables that have vertical headers?

By vertical header I mean that the table has the header (`<th>`) tag on the left side (generally)

> **Header 1** data data data
> **Header 2** data data data
> **Header 3** data data data

They look like this, so far I've come up with two options

### First Option

```html
<table id="vertical-1">
    <caption>First Way</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The main advantage of this way is that you have the headers right (actually left) next to the data it represents, what I don't like however is that the `<thead>`, `<tbody>` and `<tfoot>` tags are missing, and there's no way to include them without breaking the nicelly placed together elements, which lead me to the second option.

### Second Option

```html
<style type="text/css">
    #vertical-2 thead,#vertical-2 tbody{
        display:inline-block;
    }
</style>
<table id="vertical-2">
    <caption>Second Way</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">Header 1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">Header 2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">Header 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>row 1</td>
            <td>row 1</td>
            <td>row 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">Footer</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

The main advantage here is that you have a fully descriptive html table, the drawbacks are that proper representation needs a bit of CSS for the `tbody` and `thead` tags and that the relation between the headers and data isn't very clear as I had my doubts when creating the markup.

---

So, both ways render the table how it should, here a pitcure:

[image: render]
With the headers on the left or right side if you would prefer it, so, any suggestions, alternatives, browser issues?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

First, your second option isn't quite valid HTML in the sense that all of the rows (TR) in a table should contain an equal number of columns (TD). Your header has 1 while the body has 3. You should use the colspan attribute to fix that.

**Reference:** "The THEAD, TFOOT, and TBODY sections must contain the same number of columns." - [Last paragraph of section 11.2.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3).

**With that being said**, the first option is the better approach in my opinion because it's readable regardless of whether or not I have CSS enabled. Some browsers (or search engine crawlers) don't do CSS and as such, it'll make your data make no sense as the header will then represent columns instead of rows.

Comment: Is it really necessary for him to fix that first problem you mentioned? Since if you only add one cell, it automatically takes the first space and the rest gets ignored?

Comment: hi thanks for highlighting the invalid markup, I'll correct it.

Comment: @Nideo - I've added a reference from the HTML4 documentation in my post that clearly states that THEAD, TFOOT and TBODY must contain the same number of columns.

Comment: @Triztian - One more thing. The TFOOT should be directly below the THEAD (and before the TBODYs). Again, this is covered in section 11.2.3 of the HTML specification.

Comment: SO, does adding the `colspan` attribute to the headers we validate the markup?

Comment: Is the `scope` attribute for `th` tags still valid? I always assume you use the first approach and then you do `th scope="row"` or is the `scope` definition supposed to be used in `thead`?

Comment: @Triztian - Adding the `colspan` attribute to the columns in the THEAD and TFOOT and moving the TFOOT above the TBODY will make it proper HTML... but it won't make it right. Again, think about visually impaired people, web crawlers, etc. that don't use CSS. Your table won't make any sense. You should be able to look at the table without any CSS and still be able to understand it.

Comment: @prodigitalson - The `scope` attribute wouldn't really make much of a difference in this case. If you read what it's for, you'll understand. It basically means that the that columns is the header for either the row or column it contains. The problem is it's use doesn't make sense unless if was to replace the `<th>` with a `<td scope="row">`.

Answer (score 5):

The First Option...  I think it is the better and simple approach..

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, option 1. I would suggest you to look at this example from W3.org(link below). I think this method is the best, because this way your headings will also be interpreted right on screen readers.

https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/one-header/#table-with-header-cells-in-the-first-column-only

Answer (score -6):

```css
div.vertical {
  margin-left: -85px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 215px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* Safari/Chrome */
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* Firefox */
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* Opera */
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* IE 9 */
}

th.vertical {
  height: 220px;
  line-height: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="vertical">
        <div class="vertical">Really long and complex title 1</div>
      </th>
      <th class="vertical">
        <div class="vertical">Really long and complex title 2</div>
      </th>
      <th class="vertical">
        <div class="vertical">Really long and complex title 3</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Example</td>
      <td>a, b, c</td>
      <td>1, 2, 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation as to how your answer addresses the issue identified in the question.