# Is a table with top and left headers possible using thead and tbody?

Tags: html

I wish to layout two dimensional data in a HTML table, an example

```
      Cow  Horse
  Big   1    3
Small   5    7
```

I can easily achieve this with the following markup.

```
<table>
    <tr><th></th><th>Cow</th><th>Horse</th></tr>
    <tr><th>Big</th><td>1</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Small</th><td>5</td><td>7</td></tr>
</table>
```

However, I've been wondering whether this is possible with tbody and thead tags?

I've tried this, but the data just appears below the headers, which is kind of what I expect, but don't want.

```
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr><th></th><th>Cow</th><th>Horse</th></tr>
     <tr><th>Big</th><th></th><th></th></tr>
     <tr><th>Small</th><th></th><th></th></tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr><td></td><td>1</td><td>3</td></tr>
     <tr><td></td><td>5</td><td>7</td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Result

```
      Cow  Horse
  Big   
Small   
        1    3
        5    7
```

Is this possible, or can thead only be used for headers at the top or side, but not both simultaneously. I can't find any examples of this problem online, perhaps I'm searching for the wrong thing.

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html
- http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368061/most-common-way-of-writing-a-html-table-with-vertical-headers) is kind of close, but only deals with headers on left, not at top too.

Comment: IMO you'll get same answer of last link you posted. K.I.S.S. `<thead>` contains header **rows**, if you change that then it's not `<thead>` any more (at least in concept). `<th>` inside `<tbody>` isn't a visual trick: both works and define meaning (so it's friendly to any browser and screen reader).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wish to use `thead` and `tbody` elements, then the former should contain the header rows and the latter all the other rows:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th></th><th>Cow</th><th>Horse</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>Big</th><td>1</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Small</th><td>5</td><td>7</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```