# Styling multiple alternate table rows

Tags: html, css

I currently have a "vertical table" (i.e. the headings are on the right). The html looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>1</th><td>1</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>1</th><td>1</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>1</th><td>1</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>2</th><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><th>2</th><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><th>2</th><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><th>3</th><td>3</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>3</th><td>3</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>3</th><td>3</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>4</th><td>4</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>4</th><td>4</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>4</th><td>4</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>5</th><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><th>5</th><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><th>5</th><td>5</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to style each "data chunk" - the three rows with `1`, three rows with `2`, etc. in an even or odd basis - within each `tbody`.

### My first idea was to use `tr:nth-child(odd)`; however, that does this:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>1</th><td>1</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>1</th><td>1</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>1</th><td>1</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>2</th><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><th>2</th><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><th>2</th><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><th>3</th><td>3</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>3</th><td>3</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>3</th><td>3</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>4</th><td>4</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>4</th><td>4</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>4</th><td>4</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>5</th><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><th>5</th><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><th>5</th><td>5</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Which does not work.

---

I then tried styling it by `tbody` (`tbody:nth-child(odd)`) but that obviously did not work.

---

### Another one I tried was `:nth-child(-n+3)` which created this result:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
}
tr:nth-child(-n+3) {
  background-color: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>1</th><td>1</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>1</th><td>1</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>1</th><td>1</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>2</th><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><th>2</th><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><th>2</th><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><th>3</th><td>3</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>3</th><td>3</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>3</th><td>3</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>4</th><td>4</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>4</th><td>4</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>4</th><td>4</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>5</th><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><th>5</th><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><th>5</th><td>5</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It's close, but only gets the first "data-chunk" (as I am calling it).

---

### I am looking for a pure-css way to style multiple alternate table rows, something which would look like this:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
}
.style-me {
  background-color: steelblue;
}
tbody:before{
  content: 'new tbody';
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="style-me"><th>1</th><td>1</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr class="style-me"><th>1</th><td>1</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr class="style-me"><th>1</th><td>1</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>2</th><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><th>2</th><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><th>2</th><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr class="style-me"><th>3</th><td>3</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr class="style-me"><th>3</th><td>3</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr class="style-me"><th>3</th><td>3</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="style-me"><th>4</th><td>4</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr class="style-me"><th>4</th><td>4</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr class="style-me"><th>4</th><td>4</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>5</th><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><th>5</th><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><th>5</th><td>5</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**However, instead of using classes it uses a css selector/pseudo class/element (maybe `:nth-of-type`?) to style the odd groupings of rows as the amount of grouping of rows is unknown (it's a dynamic table)**

*This [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652311/css-styling-multiple-alternate-table-rows/39652426?noredirect=1#comment66607897_39652426) in the answers which best describes what I am looking for*.

Comment: one question: why are you using *`<th>`* and *`<td>`* in the same row and also within *`<tbody>`* ?

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay a) I am trying to make a [vertical table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368061/most-common-way-of-writing-a-html-table-with-vertical-headers) and b) on the two `tbody`s it is how the data is separated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/Lg9cwwxn/2/

HTML

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
}
tbody:before {
  content: 'new tbody';
}

tr:nth-child(even):nth-child(3n-1) {
  background-color: steelblue;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: steelblue;
}

tr:nth-child(odd):nth-child(6n-1) {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>1</th><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><th>1</th><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><th>1</th><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><th>2</th><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><th>2</th><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><th>2</th><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><th>3</th><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><th>3</th><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><th>3</th><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><th>4</th><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><th>4</th><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><th>4</th><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><th>5</th><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><th>5</th><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><th>5</th><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><th>6</th><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><th>6</th><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><th>6</th><td>6</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>7</th><td>7</td></tr> 
    <tr><th>7</th><td>7</td></tr> 
    <tr><th>7</th><td>7</td></tr> 
    <tr><th>8</th><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr><th>8</th><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr><th>8</th><td>8</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Logic behind codes:

1. Get the Odd and change the background. :nth-child(odd)
2. Get the even child which also a 3n-1. The expression is 3(n) - 1
   So, 3(1)-1 = 2, 3(2)-1 = 5, and so on.
3. Also same in odd. 6n-1 is also 6(n) - 1.

Number 2 : will be `tr:nth-child(even):nth-child(2) and so on.`

Number 3 : will be `tr:nth-child(even):nth-child(5) and so on.`

Sorry I am not good at explaining. But I hope you get the logic behind my code.

Updated. Sorry it took so long. But here's what you want. Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you; however, this does not work if more rows are added to a `tbody`. I updated your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg9cwwxn/1/) with more rows so you can see

Comment: Ahh. I get what you want. It's like odd even but grouped into three. Wait. I'll try it.

Comment: Updated @4lackof. Is that what you want?

Comment: well that definitely works! Thanks a ton! Would you mind explaining how it works, just so that I can use it or modify it if my table needs to change?

Comment: of course! I just am testing it out, making it work if I had 4 rows instead of three, etc.

Comment: @4lackof 4 rows would be different logic. Just a mathematical calculations. Hope you get it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the snippet below:

### Code Snippet:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
}
table > tbody:first-child > tr:first-child, 
table > tbody:first-child > tr:nth-of-type(2), 
table > tbody:first-child > tr:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: steelblue;
}

table > tbody:first-child > tr:last-child, 
table > tbody:first-child > tr:nth-last-of-type(2), 
table > tbody:first-child > tr:nth-last-of-type(3) {
  background-color: steelblue;
}

table > tbody:nth-of-type(2) > tr:first-child, 
table > tbody:nth-of-type(2) > tr:nth-of-type(2), 
table > tbody:nth-of-type(2) > tr:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>1</th><td>1</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>1</th><td>1</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>1</th><td>1</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>2</th><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><th>2</th><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><th>2</th><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><th>3</th><td>3</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>3</th><td>3</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>3</th><td>3</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>4</th><td>4</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>4</th><td>4</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>4</th><td>4</td></tr> <!-- style this -->
    <tr><th>5</th><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><th>5</th><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><th>5</th><td>5</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```